# Retry network calls in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

How to make retry network calls when network errors appear with rxJava in Android.

Here is my rxJave code:

```
RxTextView.textChanges(searchInput)
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(CharSequence::toString)
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .switchMap(query -> getTypedPlaces(query))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(results -> showResult(results));
```

It works very well but I need to retry network request when connection was down.

Comment: Have you tried [`retry()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html) operator?

Comment: In order to use retry() firstly I have to detect network connection.How can I detect network connection if has network error how can i retry again

Comment: You can look into [`retryWhen()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html#collapseRxJava)

Comment: ok can I u give some code??

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not that good with Rx, all I know is that you'll need to use `retryWhen()` ^_^

Answer (score -1):

Make a `PublishSubject` and add `retryWhen(subject)`.

Then listen for changes to connectivity and when the network becomes available call `subject.onNext(null)` and if your rx-chain is stalling on that it will retry.

```
.switchMap(query -> getTypedPlaces(query).retryWhen(subject))
```

other notes...

`.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` is superfluous as the events on the TextView originate from the mainThread.

`.observeOn(Schedulers.io())` may not be necessary or you could just set the scheduler specifically in debounce.

Comment: .retryWhen(observable -> observable.flatMap(throwable -> {
                    if (throwable instanceof RetrofitError) {
                        if (((RetrofitError) throwable).getKind() == RetrofitError.Kind.NETWORK)
                        return Observable.error(throwable);
                    }
                    return Observable.timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }))
                .subscribe(results -> showResult(results), error->setError(error.getMessage()));
it can detect network state but can not retry